# How much RAM can I really use?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have a Lenovo G510, running Windows 10 Home 32-bit, and 4 GB RAM, but on the Task manager it shows that I can use only 1.5 GB of it.

In order to speed up my computer and free ram, I've downloaded Wise Memory Optimizer, and it shows that I can use only 2.5 GB.

So, how much RAM can I really use? And if it less than 4 GB, then how can I use really 4 GB?

Comment: Why aren't you running Windows in 64-bit mode?

Comment: I agree, just move to 64bit.

Comment: Memory optimizers are shams. Yes they give you more free ram, but it does it at the cost of making the OS slower.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, **Windows 32 bit (any version) allows you to use a maximum 3.5 GB of memory**. For anything more, you need to go to the 64 bit versions.

Depending on your computer's age, it can be that 3.5 GB are available right away (obviously not in your case), there might be settings in the BIOS that need to be set to allow to go from 2 GB to 3.5 GB, and it could be it does not support any more than 2 GB.

Note that from the hard limit at 3.5 GB, the graphics card typically draws a bit - most cards should be good getting 16 MB or 32 MB, but if you set in the BIOS to give it 1 GB, then that memory is gone from your total in Windows (and the graphics card cannot make any use of it really).